# Type error when using Tanstack Query's useQueries()

Tags: react-query, tanstackreact-query

I am having trouble with the useQueries functionality of Tanstack Query (formerly known as React Query).

This example [from the documentation](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/parallel-queries) (using some example data: `let users = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];`)

```
const userQueries = useQueries({
  queries: users.map((user) => {
    return {
      queryKey: ['user', user.id],
      queryFn: () => fetchUserById(user.id),
    }
  }),
});
```

renders a type error:

`Argument of type '{ queries: { queryKey: (string | number)[]; queryFn: () => any; }[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'readonly any[]'.`

`Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'queries' does not exist in type 'readonly any[]'.ts(2345)`

Is the documentation wrong or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of React Query are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 3.39.3.

Comment: Ok, in that case. You're looking on documentation for v4, the v3 is here https://tanstack.com/query/v3/docs/react/reference/useQueries. The API is different.

Comment: that's the right answer. Here's a TS playground for v4 showing that it works: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMCKz1WO1OAXzgDMoIQ4ByAARgEMA7VRgYwGsB6KdBtmAFoAjjigBPagCgpAG3Tw0uQgF44AbSTAAJgC44ARmIAaRHB36ATCbMW4AZmIBdANwzt6NrIa8yyJgLAEExkCmwAFgCqGFAAQuIAktoAFHZMyCAARrgAlPoAChQgwBgAPFp6cOlZuKZMDCDo+qx4TADmxAB8MmzBrCgx2Lj4qgNYYiPJCFJwcKLDBPpKUKgAdCAMYMnJyzlwKp2IM7NwvDDIUCHTJyfzEgDS6OL66tTL1KbLqzpOxsc3d3EADEmPpknsDqEYBForh4kkdjFvtocn8bkRjkRUVIsW4pMshngCFIuFw4AA9AD8QA